# How can I alternately solve or otherwise optimize the solution to finding paths up a ladder 1 or 2 steps at a time?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I got thrown off by an interview question recently,

> What structure do you use to find all the ways up a ladder with N
>   steps in 1 or 2 steps moves?

It occured to me today that a graph expansion could be used but it's not optimal because when N = 30, it evalates almost 700,000 nodes on a single round of expansion.

Here's the output of solving for N = 5.

```
2 2 1
2 1 2
1 2 2
2 1 1 1
1 2 1 1
1 1 2 1
1 1 1 2
1 1 1 1 1
```

My instinct is that maybe this problem can be solved with regular methods from Discrete Math that I'm just not remembering.

Is there a way to get the set of sequences containing (1, 2) where the sum of the elements is N?

If anyone is interested [here's the code](https://gist.github.com/2913668) of the program I wrote.

Comment: So, just to be sure: you want to actually print all the paths not just the amount of paths?

Comment: Yes, i was asked to say how I'd find all the paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $N=0$ there is one way: $\langle\rangle$. (No steps at all.) If $N=1$, there is one way, $\langle 1\rangle$. For $N>1$, take each way up a ladder of $N-2$ steps and append a $2$, and each way up a ladder of $N-1$ steps and append a $1$. Thus, for $N=2$ you get $\langle 2\rangle$ and $\langle 1,1\rangle$. The first few stages, with semicolons separating the paths derived from two steps back from those derived from one step back:

$$\begin{align*}
&N=0: \langle\rangle\\
&N=1: \langle 1\rangle\\
&N=2: \langle 2\rangle;\langle 1,1\rangle\\
&N=3: \langle 1,2\rangle;\langle 2,1\rangle,\langle 1,1,1\rangle\\
&N=4: \langle 2,2\rangle,\langle 1,1,2\rangle;\langle 1,2,1\rangle,\langle 2,1,1\rangle,\langle 1,1,1,1\rangle
\end{align*}$$

You never need to have more than two consecutive levels in storage at once, and it’s a straightforward generation with no trial and error. By the way, the number of paths for a given $N$ is $F_{N+1}$, the $(N+1)$-st [Fibonacci number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number),

Answer (score 2):

The number of such paths is the Fibonacci number $F_{n+1}$.

You can get the set $S_n$ of $n$-step paths recursively: append $1$ to each member
of $S_{n-1}$, $2$ to each member of $S_{n-2}$, and take the union.

Comment: Heh. Beat me to the answer by 1 minute.